# Occupacion: Op de computador

Tags: significado

I have seen it in a passport in lane "occupacion". maybe it is shortened but I hardly can understand.
could you please help me?

Comment: "operador"? (15 chars)

Comment: I’m not sure which sort of passport you were looking at, given that *occupacion* is a spelling peculiar to Old French and Middle English. That word is now spelled *occupation* in present-day French and English; *ocupação* in Portuguese; *ocupación* in various “Spanish” languages including Castilian, Asturian, Galician, and Aragonese; *ocupació* in Catalan; *occupazione* in Italian; and *ocupație* in Romanian. All derive from the Latin *occupātio, occupātiōnis*.

Answer (score 1):

"Op de Computador" could be a occupation/profession.

By definition it is a person who uses the computer. It is a generic occupation in from a computer. It is not a specialist or a technical.